# Conditional termination of parallel tasks in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have O(n<sub>c</sub>) tasks to run in parallel, where n<sub>c</sub> is the number of cores available. Three exit scenarios must be supported:

1. Wait until all tasks are finished
2. When a condition is met, stop all currently running tasks and stop creating new tasks
3. When an exception in any of the child processes is raised, stop all currently running tasks, stop creating new tasks, and pass the exception to the main process.

What are the common practices for implemeting this?